# applescript file name error

Tags: applescript, filenames

I have a spreadsheet that our office uses for scheduling.  Each tab represents a month.  I am able to export each tab to a file named month1.csv, month2.csv... etc.  I have the following piece of code to open each months file and loop through it:

```
    repeat with b from 1 to 12
            tell application "Finder"
            set curFileName to (sourceFolder & "month" & b & ".csv") as string
            --display dialog curFileName
            set workingFile to read file (curFileName)
            --display dialog "File has been read"
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {ASCII character 13}
            set theContents to text items of workingFile as list
        end tell

do stuff with the csv...

end repeat
```

The script iterates through the first month and then when b = 2 I get this error:

```
Finder got an error: File file Macintosh HD:Users:lorenjz:Documents:Manpower:,month,2,.csv wasn’t found.
```

What do I need to do to eliminate this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following line instead of yours. Basically you are trying to add text together to create a file path. However sourceFolder is not text so you must first make that into text before you can add more text to it. "b" is also not text so that has to be coerced to text too.

In general applescript is good about coercing things for you. It basically tries to coerce everything into the class of the first object in the line. So if you make sourceFolder into text (it's a file specifier unless you coerce it) then applescript will try to coerce everything after that to text... meaning that you really wouldn't have to coerce "b" to text because applescript will do that for you... as long as souceFolder is text of course. I generally do the coercing myself though to make sure it is correct so I would generally also coerce "b" myself.

The point is that when you add text together everything must be text. You can't just put "as text" at the end of the line, you must coerce every individual item to text. Good luck.

```
set curFileName to (sourceFolder as text) & "month" & (b as text) & ".csv"
```